# How to replace 'NA' in different columns with blank in sql?

Tags: sql

I am trying to scan and replace all the 'NA'  with blanks in all the columns in Sql.
e.g. replacing all the NA in Column Data A - Data C with Blank .

```
DataA   DataB  DataC -----> DataA  DataB  DataC
NA       12      10                 12     10
10       NA      NA          10
```

Comment: Can you please tag the database you are using

Comment: standard Sql will not help with "not specifying the column name", some dialect-specific constructs will help... but the code will be complex, and not worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nullif()`:

```
select nullif(dataA, 'NA') as dataA,
       nullif(dataB, 'NA') as dataB,
       nullif(dataC, 'NA') as dataC
from t;
```

Comment: is there anyway of not specifying the column name and scan through the whole table and replace the NA?

Comment: do yoy want to update the table? or just select modified select..?

Comment: Just modify the table and remove all the NA and replace them with blank

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to replace the value of `NA` in column `DataA` of table `tablename`, you use this `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE table SET DataA = NULL WHERE DataA = 'NA';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select
case when DataA = 'NA' then null else DataA end as DataA,
case when DataB = 'NA' then null else DataB end as DataC,
case when DataC = 'NA' then null else DataB end as DataC
from table_name;
```